# Understanding the math behind using maximum likelihood for linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, maximum-likelihood

I understand both terms, linear regression and maximum likelihood, but, when it comes to the math, I am totally lost. So I am reading this article [*The Principle of Maximum Likelihood*](http://complx.me/2017-01-22-mle-linear-regression/) (by Suriyadeepan Ramamoorthy). It is really well written, but, as mentioned in the previous sentence, I don't get the math.

The joint probability distribution of $y,\theta, \sigma$ is given by (assuming $y$ is normally distributed):

[image: joint probability distribution of y,θ,σ]

This equivalent to maximizing the log likelihood:
[image]

The maxima can be then equating through  the derivative of l(θ) to zero:
[image]

I get everything until this point, but don't understand how this function is equivalent to the previous one :
[image]

Comment: This kind of question goes well on Maths Stack Exchange.

Comment: @RobertFrost I think this type of questions can be asked here, given the topic (maximum likelihood and linear regression). AI is still a mathematical-based field, so this type of questions are normal in the AI field too. Honestly, I would like to see more questions of this kind here.

Comment: @nbro me too, I was just saying in case you wanted more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that the first $=$ (equals) in $\frac{dl(\theta)}{d\theta} 
 = 0 = −\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(0−2X^TY + X^TX \theta)$ should be interpreted as a "is set to", that is, we set $\frac{dl(\theta)}{d\theta} 
 = 0$. Given that (apparently) $\frac{dl(\theta)}{d\theta} = −\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(0−2X^TY + X^TX \theta)$, $\frac{dl(\theta)}{d\theta} 
 = 0$ is equivalent to $0 = −\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(0−2X^TY + X^TX \theta)$.

Now, let's apply some basic linear algebra:

\begin{align}
0 &= −\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(0−2X^TY + X^TX \theta) \iff \\
0 &= −(0−2X^TY + X^TX \theta) \iff \\
0 &= −0 + 2X^TY - X^TX \theta) \iff \\
0 &= 2X^TY - X^TX \theta \iff \\
X^TX \theta &= 2X^TY \iff \\
(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX) \theta &= (X^TX)^{-1}2X^TY \iff \\
\theta &= (X^TX)^{-1}2X^TY
\end{align}

Now, you can ignore the $2$, because it is just a constant, and, when optimizing, this does not influence the result.

Note that using $\hat{\theta}$ instead of $\theta$ is just to indicate that what we will get is an "estimate" of the real $\theta$, because of round off errors during the computations, etc.

Comment: I think it would be better to clarify under what circumstances and why, constants can be ignored. It looks at face value like doing so will halve the value of theta.

Comment: @RobertFrost I think there's a wrong derivation in the original article and that 2 would not even occur in the calculations above anymore, because it would cancel out with the 2 in the denominator. Essentially, $(Y - X\theta)^T(Y - X\theta)$ would have a term $X^TX\theta^2$ and the partial derivative of $l$ with respect to $\theta$ would produce the term $2X^TX\theta$ (but the original author of the article left out the 2 in front). In that case, after the partial derivation, all addends would have a $2$ in front, which would cancel out with the 2 at the denominator.

Comment: Maybe that's what confused the OP

Comment: @RobertFrost I think what confused the OP was that the "$= 0$" is actually "setting to $0$", but only the OP can tell us. Maybe more than one thing confused him/her.

Comment: Well , in fact, I was confused about the disappearance of 2 in the last equation. thank you very much for the detailed answer!